# Automatically adjust the phone number format in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a form element for entering phone number where it automatically adjusts the phone number format.

I didn't like the idea to put an external link showing the actual form.
So, here is my effort for animation from words.

The end result I want is this format.

```
(519) 111-1111
```

First three area code, followed by a space, region code three number, and a dash and a four number

So, once the user starts typing the first number, it automatically becomes like

```
(5
```

When three number

```
(519
```

As soon as the fourth number

```
(519) 1
```

Space and a completed bracket

As soon three number more, automatic dash

```
(519) 111-1
```

And last three numbers

```
(519) 111-1111
```

Just like that.

I am a newbie, and I have NO idea, how to do this, I am pretty sure we need jquery and javascript stuff here.

Any tips / suggestions / help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you [**tried anything so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)? :)

Comment: this is far more complex than you can imagine ... you need to account for backspace, or user moving the position of the caret, or editing (cut/copy/paste etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned jQuery, you can have a look at https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

They have one example that does exactly what you are asking for ("US Telephone")